# How to split SQL guid ranges equally between X number of shards - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, guid, uniqueidentifier, sharding

How would one go about implementing the following method?

```
public List<Tuple<SqlGuid, SqlGuid, int>> GetShardRanges(int numberOfShards);
```

- Assume UNIQUEIDENTIFIER falls between 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 and FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF (both inclusive)
- Tuples are ordered like so: Lowest allowed value, Highest allowed value, Shard number (starts from 1)
- Shard ranges need to be equally split between shards

Also, just as a point of reference, .NET guids are sorted differently than SQL guids (http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2007/08/31/how-are-guids-sorted-by-sql-server.aspx)

Comment: "Shard ranges need to be equally split between shards" - what if `numberOfShards` isn't equal to 0 modulo `2^128`? Also, should we take into consideration the types of GUIDs involved?

Comment: In my case, numberOfShards will always be an even number greater than 0. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the types of GUIDs. I only need to use Guid and/or SqlGuid .NET classes.

Comment: There are different types of Guids. For example, `Guid.NewGuid` always creates a type 4 Guid (as does SQL's `NEWID()`). SQL's `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` creates a type 1 Guid. If say, you asked for 4 shards and we sharded based on the type, then all type 1 guids end up in one shard, all type 2 in another, etc. But if you're only generating e.g. type 4 guids, then *all* of the values you're working with end up in a single shard.

Comment: It's definitely going to be a type 4 Guid.